# Search matching multiple distinct senders

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

How does one perform a search such that it matches multiple distinct senders in the sense that one may match emails from different senders. I.e. if you have received emails from the senders

```
alice@foo.com
```

and

```
bob@bar.com
```

what query would yield all emails from both `alice` and `bob`, regardless of whether or not they are joint recipients on an email or distinct senders?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following filter in your search bar:

```
from:(alice@foo.com OR bob@bar.com)
```

This way allows even more complicated queries with several levels of parenthesis using the logical `and` and `or` operators. The same would work with destination addresses, replacing the keyword `from` with `to`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, using the ubiquitous "or" token `||`, we get

```
alice || bob
```

Comment: Gmail use `|` as the OR operator.

Comment: It seems GMail allows for both `|` and `||`.